# Calling a stored procedure with a select

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a query and i have to put it in a stored procedure but when I call the stored procedure it doesn´t return anything;

This is my query:

```
select * from mdc_cat_parametros where param_llave='SMTP_SERVER';
```

When I execute the query it returns one row but the stored procedure doesn´t.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE
AS
    RT MDC_CAT_PARAMETROS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO RT FROM MDC_CAT_PARAMETROS WHERE PARAM_LLAVE='SMTP_SERVER';
END MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE;
```

I call the stored procedure:

```
EXECUTE MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stored procedure is populating `RT` but you then need to select out of it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE (results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
    RT MDC_CAT_PARAMETROS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO RT FROM MDC_CAT_PARAMETROS WHERE PARAM_LLAVE='SMTP_SERVER';
    OPEN results FOR SELECT * FROM RT;
END MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE;
```

or you could simplify it to get rid of the `RT` variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE (results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN results FOR 
    SELECT * FROM MDC_CAT_PARAMETROS WHERE PARAM_LLAVE='SMTP_SERVER';
END MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: The first suggest shows "The tabla or view doesn´t exist", the second compiles correctly but how do i call the procedure, I try with EXECUTE MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE; but shows something about parameters PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE'

Comment: variable rc refcursor;
exec MDC_UTIL_PROCEDURE( :rc );
print rc;     I SOLVED THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is just fetching the result set into a local variable in the procedure.  When the procedure exits, the variable is no longer in scope.  If you want to return data from a select, you need to use a ref cursor.  Here is a link to some [good examples](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php)